# Paid the seller but did not receive my Bitcoin

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I bought my bitcoins from Remitano, the support team said it's been released but it's already 2 days I still haven't receive anything.

The following is my e-wallet : 17PvSJNcr8giYNDivs5z1CFiXYvV8Lh4NA

And the transaction is as below.

https://blockexplorer.com/tx/c0c40897b9a1c4d10c8c6ee692a7d6e4a475658fb4d8d451fd0d926ba4127a46

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: We can't help you. If that company (never heard of it) does not deliver it probably means they ran away with your money.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the 17PvS.. address, there are a number of transactions in and out. It is perhaps worth mentioning that by design, bitcoin addresses should be used just once, to help protect your financial privacy.

The transaction ID you linked is for a [transaction that has been confirmed](https://blockchain.info/tx/c0c40897b9a1c4d10c8c6ee692a7d6e4a475658fb4d8d451fd0d926ba4127a46), if the funds are not appearing in your wallet then I would guess that either your wallet is out of sync with the network, or someone has hacked your wallet and stolen the coins. Considering the 17PvS.. has outgoing transactions after the transaction you linked, I fear the latter may be the case for you.

(Also, for what its worth, I would not use blockexplorer.com. They have decided to refer to bitcoin cash as bitcoin, which makes using their site very confusing. In my answer I assume you are using bitcoin, and not bitcoin cash)

Comment: I would second that comment on blockexplorer.com, the site was bought out and switched to bicoin cash, which is massively confusing as you say.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time! Does that mean there is nothing else i can do to retrieve them?

Comment: If you do not control the addresses the coins were transferred to (after leaving 17PvS...), then you will have to contact whoever owns that address and ask for them back. There is no other way, transactions are not reversible or refundable.

Comment: how do I contact that person? Any way I can know who is that person?

Comment: You would have to find that info out for yourself, identity is not built into The blockchain. If it wasn’t you that moved the coins, chances are it was a malicious actor so unfortunately they are likely gone. Sorry for your loss :(